# Splitting Lines of a text file and outputting data to file

Tags: file, file-io, python-3.x, split

So I have my code and I am trying to split the lines to get a desired output the file data looks like this 
{}
ID event
1   alpha mike
1   bravo
2   xray zebra
this is an error message
2   alpha
3   charlie
2   hotel

and the output is supposed to look like this

{}

ID event
1   alpha mike, bravo
2   xray zebra, alpha, hotel
3   charlie

Here is my current code, I know not efficient and kind of rough and does not work.

```
global file
file = open ("sample.txt", 'r')

outputDict={}
for line in file:
line= "1\t alpha mike bravo"
left,right=line.split('\t')
ouputDict={}
outputDict[left]=right+','
outputDict 
for line in file:
line= "2\t xray zebra alpha hotel"
left,right=line.split('\t')
ouputDict={}
outputDict[left]=right+','  
    for line in file:
line="3\t charlie"
left,right=line.split('\t')
ouputDict={}
outputDict[left]=right+','  
     if left in outputDict:
outputDict[left]=outputDict[left]+right+','
    else:
outputDict[left]=right+','
    for ind in outputDict:
file.write(ind) % ("\t") % (outputDict[ind])
```

Comment: Do you care if answers are not in Python? Because you didn't include the Python tag.

Comment: Yeah it is python sorry will add tag

Comment: can you fix your indenting?